# osCommerce 2.3 - Unable to determine the page link

Tags: php, oscommerce

I have a problem in osCommerce 2.3

PHP/5.6.31

I have tried to setup on my localhost but it will return an error message.

So how can I fix this problem

Is there any problem in the configuration?

---

Error!

```
Unable to determine the page link!
```

Function used:

```
tep_href_link('', '', 'NONSSL')
```

---

Answer (score 1):

If you look in `catalog/includes/functions/html_output.php`, you'll see the function definition for `tep_href_link`.  It's

`function tep_href_link($page = '', $parameters = '', $connection = 'NONSSL', $add_session_id = true, $search_engine_safe = true) {`

You have provided a blank first parameter. If you look at some examples in the catalog directory, you'll see they provide a first parameter, generally drawn from a define in `includes/filenames.php`.

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same issue and on debug found this issue comes due to `tep_href_link(basename($PHP_SELF)`  `$PHP_SELF` is not working properly return blank and got fixed just placing

```
$PHP_SELF=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
define('CONFIGURE_STATUS_COMPLETED', 1);
```

at the bottom of `includes/configure.php` and it worked.